# Windows 10 won't shut down, any ideas?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 machine that won't shut down. It logs out the current user and then it stops there. When I try to shut down from the log in screen I see a cmd pop up and disappear very quickly and the shut down doesn't happen.

Any ideas how to find what's happening?

Comment: Do you get a message about a process blocking the shutdown?

Comment: Check the Windows system event log. There you should find details what's happening when you try to shut down the system.

Comment: What happens when you run the CMD *shutdown /s /t 0* ? Or if  you *force* it with *shutdown /s /f /t 0*?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have almost the same problem (no cmd window, and shutting down from login screen actually works). Your first command results in a logoff, while your second in a shutdown. What does that indicate?

Comment: @Andreas, since you have a similar issue, see the answer below. The OP has *not* responded,

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the reply! I'll be sure to check and try your answer out next opportunity I get.

Answer (score 1):

A user states, `shutdown /s /t 0`, which attempts to shut down gracefully, waiting for all apps to close, fails, i.e., only logs the user off.

It is also stated, `shutdown /s /f /t 0`, which uses the `/f` argument to *force* shutdown, even with apps still running, *does* work.

Evidently, there is *some* process running, either [one started at logoff through Group Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017542/how-to-schedule-a-windows-task-to-be-run-at-logoff), or one *not* owned by the user, that refuses to shut down gracefully. There are a few options, then, to insure the PC actually shuts down.

- Use *Task Manager* to find the errant process.

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the app.
  - Click on *Details* tab.
  - Click on *User name* column header to sort by user.
  - Look for any process that might be causing the issue, particularly one not owned by you.
- Check *Group Policies* (GPO) for a shbutdown task.

  - Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, then type and select `gpedit.msc` if it installed on the PC.
  - If the *Group Policy Editor* is *not* available, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, then type and select `regedit`. Look for the the key  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown`. If there is an entry, that is the likely culprit. **N.B.: if this PC is under corporate control, check with IT before making *any* change!**
- Do a thorough scan for malware. Perhaps your PC is busy mining cryptocurrency, and the malefactors want it to keep running.
- **Finally, if all else fails**, make a batch script with just `shutdown /s /f /t 0`. Create shortcut to it, and use that shortcut tp *immediately* shut down. Of course, this is not a graceful way to end a session, and might leave data unwritten! And., of course, it does not find out what causes the issue.

Comment: I was unable to recreate the problem at will, but I'll try this out next time it happens